# PHP, iOS & Android RESTful best practise

Tags: php, apache, rest

I am planning on developing a RESTful web application in PHP, and then use the same web services with iOS and Android apps. On the web application login, I am going to send the user credentials via ajax & HTTPS in the authentication header.

- Is this really secure?
- Are this credentials going to be remembered in every new request I make and page in the domain I visit?
- Do I have to configure anything on my Apache server?
- Where do I have to redirect to the login page if the credentials are wrong or aren't set?

I plan on checking in my PHP code if the user exists, and if not, return an error code but this won't redirect to the login page. I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https is indeed secure. Or at least it's the best we have. Of course you have to be careful to *always* use https, don't send some data over http or you may open up avenues of attack.

The usual way to do authentication is to log in once, and give a temporary token back (like a session in traditional web apps), which can be used for all later requests. This allows you to revoke the token at any time (or maybe after a set time). You can go further, with tokens that change with each request, but you're getting into very complicated territory.

Your apache server should need no special configuration, although RESTful services often use server-side redirects (e.g. `/myresource/` goes to my `script.php?i=myresource`) or other tricks to make nicer URLs possible.

For the last point, there's no concept of redirecting the client in RESTful APIs (well, there is but it's different). The point is that each request performs a specific task, or fails. It's up to the client application to deal with errors (e.g. Show the login page again)

---

To go into more detail on authentication:

Unfortunately I can't find the original article which suggests this, and I may have some parts wrong, but this method is the most secure I've seen:

- user logs in by calling a particular login page, the page generates 2 long (maybe 32 characters) and completely random tokens (call them A and B) and sends them back (and stores the values in a database). For better reliability it can check the database to make sure the B token is unique, but randomness will usually avoid that and it's no security risk.
- each time the user makes a new request, they send both tokens. The server checks that both match, and knows who the user is from the database (according to token B). It then generates a new random token which replaces A, and sends this back (whether the API request was successful or not.
- the client updates its A token with the new token, and can use it got future requests.

If the server gets an invalid B token, authentication has failed. If it gets an invalid A token but a valid B token, it assumes the account is compromised and logs the user out (removes the tokens from the database). It can also log the user out at any time it likes by deleting the values from the database (similar to gmail's log-me-out-from-other-devices feature)

The downside is that if a request gets lost (lost Internet connection while making a request), the tokens will go out of sync and the user will be logged out. Also it's impossible to run multiple requests simultaneously for a single login session. Both can be improved by allowing the client api to automatically try logging in again on failure.

Quite complicated, very secure. How complex you should make your authentication depends on how secure you need it to be.

Comment: You mean like a random string I associate to the user and then save it in SESSION? How should I implement this? Saving the token in my DB? I thought I should send the credential in every request because using session variables is not RESTful. What I am trying to know is if I have to save that token or user/password anywhere or the authentication header persist in all requests to the server. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't use SESSION for a REST API. You should do something like what session does, but implement it yourself (cookies in general are not for RESTful services, and sessions use cookies). Explaining how to do that is an article, not an answer, so look it up somewhere if you're unsure. You *can* send the login credentials with each request, but not if very high security is required.

Comment: I couldn't find the article I like so I updated my answer with details on a secure authentication method.

Comment: This seems very secure, but I still can't find a way to store the tokens without session variables. Do I have to save them in JavaScript variables and send it to every page I go via GET? Is the only way I could think of doing this. Thanks again.

Comment: I get is pretty secure to have to related random tokens, but is not the same since I have to send both of them to the client when he logs in?

Comment: You would store them in a variable or database or whatever on the client side, yes. That's what cookies are anyway, it's just handled for you by the browser. I don't understand your second question though. It's possible to do the same method without the A token if you want an easier implementation, but you lose a small amount of security.

Comment: I mean that I can't see why is this more secure. If someone is able to intercept the info I send, will see the user and password on the first POST. And of course, could watch both token A and B  when they are send at the same time on the login.

Comment: The point is that if an attacker somehow intercepts a single communication (maybe something went by http by mistake), they either won't be able to do anything with it, or their interception will be noticeable (the legitimate user will be logged out). It's a layer of security beyond what is necessary, but in security design you should expect each layer to be broken by methods you aren't yet aware of. This is heavy stuff, and you probably don't need something so secure. Also this is just one way of doing it (it just happens to be a way I like)

Comment: Ok, thanks Dave. That was useful.